# Ignoring a comma when trying to build lines from a csv file

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a database table from a CSV file here is my program:

```
public class ReadCVS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
    obj.run();

}

public void run() {

    String csvFile = "/home/Downloads/Final_DA_Celeb_List - csv_cel_event.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {
        int i = 0;
        String[] row = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            i++; 
            String create = "Create Table Events"; 

            if(!(line.contains("On [Month Date "))){
                row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            }
            if(i == 1){
                for(int x = 0; x <row.length; x++){
                    System.out.println("Column "+x+" = "+row[x]);
                    switch (x){
                    case 0:
                        create = create + ("( "+row[x]+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "); 
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text, "; 
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        create = create + row[x] + " text ); "; 
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(create);
            }else{
                for(int x = 0; x <row.length; x++){
                    System.out.println("Column "+x+" = "+row[x]);
                }
            }



        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}

One sample line in my CSV reads like:

```
On [Month Date, Year] it will be [No.] [Minutes / Seconds/ Days/ Weeks / Months] since blah blah.
```

In my program I want to skip the `,` in the above line right now my program is splitting the above line into two.

So far I tried to use the if clause:

```
if(!(line.contains("On [Month Date "))){
                row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            }
```

But this does not seem to help, any ideas how I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your split command to use a RegEx expression to only split on commas that are not within square brackets:

```
String cvsSplitBy = "(?![^)(]*\\([^)(]*?\\)\\)),(?![^\\[]*\\])";
row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
```

This works for the example you have given, however the obvious limitation is that the commas that you don't split on have to be within square brackets.

Comment: I envy you for being so efficient at regex! MATE!

Comment: I am getting an invalid escape sequence on `"(?![^)(]*\([^)(]*?\)\)),(?![^\[]*\])/g";`

Comment: I've edited the answer to take work around escaping in Java, the danger of testing the RegEx outside of Java!

Comment: You should! Take a look at some tutorials online (http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and go from there. It's just logically building up a string and even though it might take a bit of trial and error, you'll get to something that matches.